# Repeat the python function using the same list value if it returns True

Tags: python, algorithm

Anyone could help finding an effective way how to create a repeat function with the list value, where True was reached?

```
my_list = [value1, value2, value3]
 def my_func():
  score = 0
  for value in my_list:
   #do something
   if value > score
   repeat my_func with value2 as long as value > score
```

I believe I could call the list once again, but it would start to iterating value1 and my goal is finding how to make a function that iterates value2 as long as conditions are True

Comment: you say dictionary, but your code shows a list. What is correct?

Comment: can you rework on your question and make it bit more clear,

Comment: Your requirement doesn't really make sense. You are not using dictionary but list, you are not passing anything into your function (the definition itself is not correct) and it is not obvious what you want to actually accomplish.

Comment: I don't think you want to *repeat* `my_func`; you just want to break out of the loop once `value` is *not* greater than `score`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I do understand your question right, but if you want to reach true at a specific value you could simply do it by a 'for'-loop:

```
my_list=[v1, v2, v3]
for i in my_list:
    if i <= crit_value:
        #Here you can call the function
        print('False')
    else:
        print('True')
        # Next line only when you want to quit the loop here
        break
```

For this example you will stay in the for loop as long as the values in the list are lower or the same as the critical value and if you are above, you will quit the loop and print 'True'

---

EDIT:

Due to the fact you mean that the values are always changing you could do it like this:

```
my_list=[v1, v2, v3]
# Now you use indices starting from zero until the number of elements in the list 
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    # I will set the number of maximum trys to 1000, this can be changed
    for j in range(1000):
        if my_list[i] <= crit_value:
            # Here you would need to reload my_list
            print('False')
        else:
            print('True')
            # To give you the actual value
            print(my_list[i])
            break
```

Comment: because I am using live data, my_list values are constantly changing. Imagine i is at v2 point of list. How am I able to make the function use v2 value as long as it returns True (using the same value of list multiple times if conditions are met, before moving to the next value)?

Comment: Look at my edit, if I understood your question right this should be it

Answer (score 0):

You could define a wrapper function, applying a given function `f` while some condition `cond` holds, then apply that function to each element of your list.

```
def repeat(func, cond, x):
    while cond(x):
        x = func(x)
    return x

>>> f = lambda x: x + 5
>>> [repeat(f, lambda x: x < 18, item) for item in [1, 3, 2]]
[21, 18, 22]
```

Or using `functools.partial` to create a new function to be applied in, e.g., `map`:

```
>>> import functools
>>> g = functools.partial(repeat, f, lambda x: x < 18)
>>> list(map(g, [1, 3, 2]))
[21, 18, 22]
```